# Scalable capital canceled my savings plan on an ETF, what are the consequences?

Tags: etf, stock-exchanges

I'm using Scalable capital to invest in ETFs, without previous experience in the financial markets.

About half a year ago, I started putting a little bit of money in what is probably an obscure ETF, Amundi MSCI Eastern Europe ex Russia UCITS ETF EUR (C). It has a high nominal value, so I now own 0.375 parts of one share, worth 98 euro. Yesterday, I got an e-mail from Scalable capital, informing me that this ETF is no longer traded on the gettex exchange, so they are canceling my savings plan.

The e-mail was very short, I am reproducing it here in full (translated from German):

> You have set up a savings plan on AMUNDI MSCI EASTERN EUROPE EX RUSSIA UCITS ETF - EUR (C) with ISIN LU1681043755. This security can no longer be traded via gettex and we cannot accept any further trading orders for this ISIN. Your savings plan was therefore automatically deactivated.
>
> Log in now to choose another ETF or stock savings plan.

My investment still gets displayed in the SC app:

[image: screenshot of app showing ETF]

I wonder what are the consequences of this event for me, especially since I have read somewhere that the ownership of partial shares through SC is a kind of financial fiction. If I do nothing for a year and we assume that everything else stays equal (especially the ETF still not being available on gettex) will I still own 0.375 of a share, or 98 euro worth of a share at the course of the day, or something else? If, on the contrary, I decide to do something now, for example to sell my partial share so I get the 98 euro, how can I do that, since SC no longer trades these shares?

Comment: Seems it isn't traded in Frankfurt, also https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/etf/amundi-msci-eastern-europe-ex-russia-ucits-etf-eur-c

Comment: whet did the letter say regarding a timeline and the default actions they will take if you don't act by a deadline?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I added the e-mail text. No such information was included, they only told me they no longer trade it.

Comment: Since I got a similar message for an ETF on Scalable Capital, would you mind telling me if it was indeed resolved by being payed out automatically, @rumtscho ?

Comment: @JannikBuhr yes, it got payed out automatically, with some delay. They held back taxes on the gains (this may be Germany-specific) and payed out the rest into the Scalable Capital "available money" pool.

Comment: Thanks! In case someone else finds this with a similar question: In my case the etf was merged into a new etf with some other, after a couple of days I automatically got this new etf and just had to set up the savings plan again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fund has been dissolved, as you can read in the following shareholder notice: https://www.amundietf.com/pdfDocuments/shareholders-notice/LU1681043755/ENG/GBR. What should happen is that shareholders that have not sold their shares yet, will be credited with their respective portion of the net asset value of the fund as determined on 15 May 2023. So most likely Scalable will pay out the value to you in cash in the near future. It is rather poor form though that they have not notified you before about the closure, as it has been known for over a month now.

Comment: Bummer. I liked this index, and I think it's still undervalued because people are edgy about the region. But it's good to know I'll be getting money, instead of it being caught in some weird limbo where the share exists but I can't sell it. I guess the amount won't be the same as the last recorded market price - let's see how much I get out of it. I guess I'll know sometime after the 15th.

Comment: There may be other ETF providers that have funds that track the same (or a similar) index, that would likely be your best bet.

Comment: @rumtscho [justETF](https://www.justetf.com/de/find-etf.html?assetClass=class-equity&index=MSCI%2BEmerging%2BMarkets%2BEastern%2BEurope%2Bex%2BRussia) lists one other funds for the same index which is available in an accumulating and one distributing variant